# Pyautogui not showing correct pixel color on Mac

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to get the pixel color of where the mouse is, and the RGB value is not even close to what it is supposed to be. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTjtb.png). I am using some basic code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
     x, y = pyautogui.position()
     print(pyautogui.pixel(x, y))
     time.sleep(1)
```

I have no clue what to do and any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: first of all, this is a nice bit of code. It seems to work fine.  when i run the same and hover over white i get `255,255,255` which is expected and a dark (not quite black) i get `30,30,30` as expected...  so in your example, can you make a red box and hover over it with the mouse and return that result pls.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Hovering over a red box returns the result: 195, 189, 216. The box's actually color according to photoshop is 255, 0, 0.

Comment: interesting.  i just drew a red box with `libre office draw` and it returns `255,0,0`. I am using `vs code` on `windows 10` and `python 3.10`...  it must be something with your system as the code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess i will switch to a windows system for this project. Can't believe that a Mac struggles to get correct pixel values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We conclude that the code works fine on a `windows 10` with `vscode` and `python 3.10`.

It appears as though this is might be a Mac specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue on mac but found that for some reason the pixel function has 2x resolution.

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print(pyautogui.pixel(x * 2, y * 2))
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your MacBook has a Retina Display, the Screenshot Resolution will be twice your Mac's Display Resolution.

`pyautogui.pixel()` relies on screenshot. `print(pyautogui.pixel(x * 2, y * 2))` will account for the doubled resolution of screenshot in a MacBook with Retina Display.

Comment: Your solution has already been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77020255/2530121). Please check all other answers before posting.

Comment: @LTyrone Thanks for the feedback. My intention was to clarify that the resolution issue stems from Retina Display, as it was ambiguous in previous responses.